# There are no files to be backed up spatie/laravel-backup

Tags: laravel, laravel-backup

I'm trying to backup a gallery folder stored in storage/app/public/gallery so I added

```
'include' => [
    base_path('storage/app/public/gallery'),
],
```

to the backup config and run 'php artisan backup:run', it gives the error
**Backup failed because There are no files to be backed up..**

I tried a different approach and change it to

```
'include' => [
    base_path('storage'),
 ],
```

The backup works but I get everything inside the storage folder except the public folder. It somehow excludes the public directory.